# Draggable and Sortable Portlets // jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

Trying to figure out but still cant find a way how I can make one droppable and sortable target for few draggable portlets.
I based on this tutorial: 
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

What i'm trying to do is [image]

The idea is to drag small portlets in to big red portlet (i already success to do) but i want to do it with aligning horizontally (means sorting, not just dropping it wherever), i succeed also to do it verticaly, not good for me(

My current js code looklike this (tried already different combinations):

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#draggablegrey" ).draggable({   });

    $( "#draggableblue" ).draggable({
     connectWith: '#droppable',


    });

 $( "#droppable" ).sortable({
     connectWith: '#droppable'  }); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery UI's website: -> "Draggables are built to interact seamlessly with sortables."

It is possible you can try to follow this example from jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Also for sorting horizontally add a line of css in your style:

```
#sortable>div { float: left; }
```

after this you should be able to move them and sort them horizontally.

This fiddle is from someone else http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/